# This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item when sharing on whatsApp

Tags: objective-c

first time app install and share image is not working, it show alert:

> This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item.

and I will try second time image share successfully. What is the issue?

```
-(void)TwitterAndmanyMore
{
    UIImage * image = _imageView.image;
    NSArray * items = @[image];
   UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

    // and present it
    [self presentActivityController:controller];
}
- (void)presentActivityController:(UIActivityViewController *)controller {

    // for iPad: make the presentation a Popover
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;

    // access the completion handler
    controller.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType,
                                              BOOL completed,
                                              NSArray *returnedItems,
                                              NSError *error)
    {
        // react to the completion
        NSLog(@"----retu------%@",returnedItems);
        if (completed)
        {

            [self showContine];
            //[self viewWillAppear:YES];
            // user shared an item
            NSLog(@"We used activity type%@", activityType);
        } else {
            // user cancelled
            NSLog(@"We didn't want to share anything after all.");
        }

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An Error occured: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: this issue is happening only in iOS 11 or in older versions too ?

Comment: till i am check on ios 11 sir

Comment: check it in ios 10 or ios 9, because i am also facing some issue with UIActivityViewController in ios 11 only. if you confirm the issue is only on ios 11 then edit your question as it is happening only in ios 11.

Answer (score 0):

use below code for this issue it work

```
-(void)TwitterAndmanyMore
{
//    UIImage * image = _imageView.image;
//    NSLog(@"Image Data %@",image);
//    NSArray * items = @[@"", image];

    tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Sample.jpg"];
    tempImage = _imageView.image;
    NSString *theMessage = @"";
    NSArray *items;

    CGImageRef cgref = [tempImage CGImage];
    CIImage *cim = [tempImage CIImage];



    if (cim != nil || cgref != NULL)
    {
        items = @[theMessage,tempImage];
    }
    else
    {
        items = @[theMessage];
    }
     NSLog(@"Image Data %@",items);
    // build an activity view controller
    UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];

    // and present it
    [self presentActivityController:controller];
}
- (void)presentActivityController:(UIActivityViewController *)controller {

    // for iPad: make the presentation a Popover
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [controller popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;

    // access the completion handler
    controller.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType,
                                              BOOL completed,
                                              NSArray *returnedItems,
                                              NSError *error)
    {
        // react to the completion
        NSLog(@"----retu------%@",returnedItems);
        if (completed)
        {

            [self showContine];
            //[self viewWillAppear:YES];
            // user shared an item
            NSLog(@"We used activity type%@", activityType);
        } else {
            // user cancelled
            NSLog(@"We didn't want to share anything after all.");
        }

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An Error occured: %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason);
        }
    };
}
```